# Block javascript activation in mobile devices - part 2

Tags: javascript, mobile, desktop

I think I am asking the question the wrong way: I need to stop javascript from activating when a device is smaller than 800 pixels.

Using Viewsource from the browser (IE 10 / 11 and Fire Fox 28 / 32) doesn't show any errors.

This is the code I am using, it does not work on a brower at 800 px or less or more than 800 px.

```js
<script>
function detectmob() {
   if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}

if(!detectmob()){
 
<script async type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/19/37402019.js"></script>  

}
</script>
```

Would someone tell me whare I have gone wrong?

Comment: In this post "Disable javascript on mobile websites" the code above is mentioned. After this code "if(!detectmob()){" there is this line:
 " //YOUR CHAT CODE" ... The question is how would I insert the javascript?  Note: When I get this to work it will be inserted in an include for certian pages on the web site.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `<script>` tags within another `<script>` tag. In order to load another JavaScript file depending on your conditions you should create the script tag on the fly, like:

```
var s = document.createElement('script'),
    h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
s.async = true;
s.src = 'http://forms.aweber.com/form/19/37402019.js';
h.parentNode.insertBefore(s, h);
```

Edit: note that inserting the script tag above outside `<head>` may not be the best option, depending on your page you could reference some other elemnent already in your head, like a link tag for CSS, then add `h = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];` instead